# Declaring the inputs of a gradle task as multiple files

Tags: android, gradle

We have a gradle task that will automatically generate codes for us before building. See the following as an example,

```
task djinniTask(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', './Djinni/run_djinni.sh'
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn djinniTask
```

Basically, the above **run_djinni.sh** is using a library [djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) to generate JNI codes. The above works fine except that it will run this script every time we build even if we didn't update the script file, which is obviously not very efficient. We did a bit of research and found [17.9. Skipping tasks that are up-to-date](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html). And as a result, the following works fine. It will skip this task if we didn't modify **run_djinni.sh**.

```
task transform {
    ext.srcFile = file('./Djinni/run_djinni.sh')
    ext.destDir = new File(buildDir, 'generated')
    doLast {
        commandLine 'sh', './Djinni/run_djinni.sh'
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, the **run_djinni.sh** is not the only script file that we have. The project is big and we multiple scripts files like: **run_foo_djinni.sh**, **run_bar_djinni.sh** and etc. **run_djinni.sh** will call each of the other scripts. So is there a way to declare the inputs of a gradle task as multiple files, for example, in our case, every files that is under the **Djinni** folder?

Comment: what if you define multiple transform tasks `transform1`, `transform2`, etc. and add `transform` task that depends on them?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, thanks for the suggestion! Actually, this will work. However, it would be nicer we could figure out a way that doesn't requires us to list out each of the files in the gradle script like this. The generated code from the **run_djinni.sh** is not only used by Android, but also our iOS project and Windows projects. Therefore, it is better to keep everything in one place. Otherwise, a future developer who added a **run_baz_djinni.sh** might not know that he needs to update both **run_djinni.sh** and the gradle scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, according to **gradle** [DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html) you can define multiple inputs:

```
task transform {
   inputs.files('file path', 'another file path')
}
```